# Meteor.js 0.6.5, Source Maps and PHPStorm 7

Tags: meteor

in Meteor.js 0.6.4 I was able to debug both client and server side code quite easily in PhpStorm 7.  I upgraded to Meteor.js 0.6.5 which added name spacing, source maps on top of other new features.  Now when I try to debug client side I can't even step into meteor functions.  On another note code completions seems to be useless as well.

Please share your experiences...

Thanks!